# Online Sources for University Level Physics (And Mathematics)

Tags: classical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

As the title suggests, I am looking for an online source for self studying physics. I am also interested in mathematics so if there is something for this to I am very interested. I want to learn it in university level. now I need classical mechanics but I believe in the future more advanced topics will be required. I've already purchased some old books online, waiting for them to arrive, but I will be happy to hear about something similar to [MIT OpenCourseWare](https://www.youtube.com/user/MIT) to watch some lectures or videos with good explanations. I used [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) for a few days but it's not exactly what I was looking for...
I also heard about edX. do you recommend any of these? or do you know about other sites which can help me?

Comment: May I ask why Khan Academy was not what you were seeking?

Comment: Maybe I just felt it's not enough... Good for introducing new concepts, or sharpening old ones, but without something else (for example a textbook) this is not working for me... That is why I am looking for texts (if you know about any cheap ones from amazon this would be helpful, old editions are totally ok)

Comment: [David Tong's lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/teaching.html) are a treasure trove of resources. They're mostly in the text form, however, they cover a lot of material and will be useful until you're in grad school.